# Is it possible for someone to send a spoofed text message via iMessage to my iPhone4?

Tags: spoofing

After the reports of the SMS spoofing security issue Apple released a statement claiming that the iMessage system was 'secure' and should be used to prevent text spoofing. I have received several harassing *SMS* spoof text messages recently and yesterday I actually received one of the harassing messages via *iMessage* from a phone number with area code matching my area.

So, is it possible that they sent a spoof text over the iMessage system or was this particular message sent from a legitimate number and iPhone user?

Comment: This question distills to "Are there any known number spoofing exploits against iMessage that Apple are unaware or in denial of?".

Answer (score 1):

It would "show up" in your iMessage but as an sms. So the background color would be green/alternative/grey to what it is normally when going through apples servers.